# React - move cards list with animation

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I have cards list with arrow to right and left
I want the cards move with animation and moving
I try framer-motion folder but the cards appear in the wrong order and also move in the wrong order
This is my code:

```
  const visibleCards = cardsT?.slice(startIndex, startIndex + 3);

  const cardVariants = {
    hidden: (direction) => ({
      x: direction === 'left' ? -500 : 500,
    }),
    visible: { x: 0 },
  };

  const getDirection = (prevIndex, newIndex) => {
    if (prevIndex > newIndex) {
      return 'left';
    } else if (prevIndex < newIndex) {
      return 'right';
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  };



return(  <>
        <div style={{ marginTop: '10px', maxWidth: '100%', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
          <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <IconButton disabled={startIndex === 0} onClick={handlePrev} style={{ height: '80px', marginTop: '80px' }}>
              <AiOutlineDoubleRight />
            </IconButton>

            {visibleCards?.map((card, index) => (

              <div style={{ padding: '60px', textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <motion.div
                  key={card.id}
                  initial={index === startIndex ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}
                  animate={index === startIndex ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}
                  custom={getDirection(startIndex, index)}
                  variants={cardVariants}
                  transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
                >
                  {/* Card content */}                
</motion.div>

              </div>
            ))}
            <IconButton disabled={startIndex + visibleCards?.length >= cards?.length} onClick={handleNext} style={{ height: '80px', marginTop: '80px' }}>
              <AiOutlineDoubleLeft />
            </IconButton>
            {/* </div> */}
          </div>
        </div></>
)
```

How should I change the code with this library so that it works properly or use another library?